# Get ecryptfs to work on centos7

Tags: rhel7, kernel-panic, ecryptfs

How can I use ecryptfs on REHL/CentOS 7.4?

`ecryptfs` is not enabled by default in Centos7 kernel config. When I enable and build the kernel, I can mount a lower ecryptfs directory into an upper directory, but get a kernel panic when doing "ls" on the upper directory.

I could paste the kernel panic but that's not the point: the question is about getting ecryptfs to work on RHEL/CentOS 7.

Notes:

- I know that Redhat deprecated ecryptfs in RHEL 7, I'm asking if someone knows how to make it work. Or knows an alternative (EnvFS is not supported either)
- I've built and installed `ecryptfs-utils` to allow mounting. Mounting works fine with both version 61 and the latest version 111 of `ecryptfs-utils`. The issue is not with `ecryptfs-utils` but with the kernel module.
- If you want to reproduce the issue, here's how I mount the `lower` directory into the `upper` directory: `sudo mount -t ecryptfs -o ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=no,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=password-file,no_sig_cache lower/ upper/`